# New functions in separate directory -- better, portable way

Tags: functions

I am just now learning WordPress theming as I have time.

Currently I have a bunch of overrides for many woocommerce defaults in my theme I have:

```
// CUSTOM FUNCTIONS
require get_template_directory() . '/woocommerce/storefunctions/woocommerce-overrides.php';
```

Is there a way to do this that is more portable? Such as if I want to change themes how can I avoid adding in the functions.php file for every theme I want to try/fiddle with. I don't know what to search for, so the question: what have I tried is: nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the thing you're looking for is **having functions.php as a plugin**. This makes it portable, regardless of the theme you are using. The most simple way is create a new file (something like my-woocommerce-functions.php) and start with the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Custom WooCommerce Functions
 * Plugin URI: http://example.com
 * Description: My Custom WooCommerce Functions
 * Author: Your Name
 * Author URI: http://example.com
 * Version: 1.0.0
 */

/* Place custom code below this line. */
require get_template_directory() . '/woocommerce/storefunctions/woocommerce-overrides.php';
?>
```

Now you have a plugin which you can activate and deactivate from dashboard. You would have to take care about file paths only (if not using get_template_directory() function).

Comment: you just improved my life tons! I made the plugin and also found a way to use the same plugin to use my own woocommerce/path-to-same/name-of-template.php file so I can add my own freaking slider and touch ready lightbox. The stuff they had was 2009 old. Thanks again!